# Unix: Command to return code

Tags: find

Here is the code I use to find and remove older files that are older than 180 days, where

PPATH=./land/arch and PERIOD=180

```
find "$PPATH" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +"$PERIOD" -exec rm -f {} \;
rt_CD=$?
echo $rt_CD
```

Regardless of whether there is a file in the directory or not I'm getting the return code as `0`.

Why is this?

If there are files it works and returns `0` and if there is no file it still returns `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The man page says:

> find exits with status 0   if  all  files  are  processed 
>   successfully, greater than  0  if  errors occur.   This is
>   deliberately a very broad description, but if the return value is
>   non-zero, you should  not  rely on the correctness of the results of
>   find.

All zero files were processed correctly, therefore a zero status is returned. It is working as specified.

If you want to detect if there are no files, you will have to capture the file-list first and then check to see if it is empty or not before sending it to `rm`.